# Java Spring + Maven Testing Error : Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-mvc

I am trying to test a get method but I receive this error unfortunately:

org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException

I am new to this and I really have no idea what I'm doing wrong. I autowired so I don't see where is the problem:

```
@RestController
public class RegisterController {


@Autowired
private UserService userService;
@Autowired
private SmtpMailSender smtpMailSender;
@Autowired
private ConfirmEmailServiceImpl confirmEmailService;

@RequestMapping(value="/register/validate",method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ResponseEntity<String> checkEmailCode(String email,String code) {

    ConfirmEmail confirmEmail=new ConfirmEmail();
    confirmEmail=confirmEmailService.findEmail(email);
    if(confirmEmail!=null && confirmEmail.getCode().compareTo(code)==0) {
            User user=userService.findByEmail(email);
            user.setActive(true);
            userService.save(user);
            return new ResponseEntity<String>("Correct",HttpStatus.OK);
        }
        else
            return  new ResponseEntity<String>("Wrong",HttpStatus.valueOf("Wrong code"));

}




}




public class RegisterControllerTest {
@InjectMocks
private RegisterController controller;

private MockMvc mockMvc;

@Before
public void setup(){

    MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);

    mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.standaloneSetup(controller).build();
}

@Test
public void test() throws Exception {

    mockMvc.perform(get("/register/validate")).andDo(print());

}
```

}

When I try to run the test I get the error

Answer (score 0):

From the Spring Boot docs

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
@Import(MyTestsConfiguration.class)
public class MyTests {

@Test
public void exampleTest() {
    ...
}

}
```

https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-testing.html

Have you tried something like this?